# How would I extract/update values in a file through a separate python script?

Tags: python, json

I am creating a simple account/password manager.
I will have pw.py run from the command line, and it will allow me to retrieve passwords, or add new ones from a file that exists in the same directory level like so:
|
|__ pw.py
|__ account_info.txt

Within pw.py, I want to import the data from account_info.txt to update, delete, or read.

Based on my reading, I believe the easiest way to do this would be to allow account_info.txt to be a JSON object, and to treat it as a dictionary from pw.py.
Is this possible?
Can I format the information in the .txt file in JSON, and from the py script,
with

```
open("account_info.txt") as account_file:  
    account_data = json.load(account_file)
```

and then input new information to update the text file by accessing the JSON dictionary like:

```
account_data[new_account] = new_password
```

Might this work? What are potential pitfalls I should look out for? Or what would be a better way to go about this?

Comment: Yes. It *might* work - if you can program the logic of it. Instead of asking "Might this work?" you should actually do it, and ask questions about the problems you face, and how to improve.

Comment: Also, it's never good idea to store passwords in plain text format.

Comment: @Michal How would you store it?

Comment: The most obvious pitfall here (except for plain text passwords) is using a relative path for the file. The path will be resolved against the current working directory, not against the directory containing your `pw.py` script. This is brittle at best and in this case a potential security hole too.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how do I dictate which directory the script should resolve the path against?

Comment: @Simonster use the magic `__file__` variable of your script and `os.path` functions (`abspath()` and `dirname()` mainly) to get the absolute path to the parent directory, then `os.path.join()` to build the full path.

Comment: @Simonster Use hashing functions, like SHA1 or at least md5